# Intentionally blur the screen on OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, display

Hey is there a tool that blurs my screen output in real time? It'd be perfect if it only blurred my external display but everything's fine.

I am on El Capitan now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xscope app has a presbyopia filter that does a light blur.

- http://xscopeapp.com

I see several large screen sizes, but you might not get your whole screen blurred. It works very well on the latest release of OS X and you can try it out for free I believe. If you're a programmer and not just looking for a ready-made tool, you would do worse to try something other than Brad Larson's tutorial on GPU accelerated video processing at http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2010/10/22/gpu-accelerated-video-processing-mac-and-ios

Comment: can't try out right now but this will be the best answer for sure, thanks bro

Comment: @user2875404 You're most welcome. Feel free to answer or change the accepted mark any time you find a better option.